# Conditioning a PDF in the intersection of two circles.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, geometric-probability

Given the diagram below (The first figure): $$f_r(r)= \frac{\lambda \pi r \exp{(-\lambda \pi r^2/2)}}{1-e^{-\lambda \pi R^2/2}}$$

where $$0<r\leq R$$

The pdf

$$f_{\text{Z}}(\text{z})=\frac{2\lambda\sqrt{R^{2}-\text{z}^{2}}}{1-e^{-\lambda\pi{R}^{2}/2}} e^{-\lambda{R}^{2}(cos^{-1}(\frac{\text{z}}{R})-(\frac{\text{z}}{R})\sqrt{1-(\text{z}/R)^{2}})}$$

where $$0<z\leq R$$

[image: Figure 1]

Question: How can this PDF be conditioned on the area UQWD given in the second figure. Note that in the second figure, the two outer circles have the same radius.

The problem is I know its possible, but I can't picture how this could be done.

[image]

Comment: In the image it seems as if the two outer circles have the same radius. Did you intend to imply this?

Comment: Yes! The two outer circles have the same radius

Comment: @Abdulhameed See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Measure-theoretic_definition).

Comment: @Alex Francisco! Thanks for sharing that link